# jQuery Datepicker not working with Rails 4 and Foundation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

For some reason my jQuery datepicker is not showing from my text field. I get error in console saying datepicker is not a function. Nothing appears from the text field:

```
 <%= f.text_field :due, class: "datepicker", placeholder: "Due", 'data-no-turbolink' => true %>
```

I did some research and saw that turbolinks might be the problem but I tried disabling turbolinks above but this seems to have no effect.

My Application.js

```
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require jquery.turbolinks  
    //= require turbolinks
    //= require list
    //= require foundation
    //= require jquery-ui/datepicker
    //= require responsive-tables
    //= require list.fuzzysearch
    //= require_tree .
$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

My Application.css.scss:

```
/*
 *= require jquery-ui/datepicker
 */


@import "foundation";
@import "main";
@import "icon-bar";
@import "style";
@import "foundation-icons";
@import "reveal"
```

JS in view

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    });
    </script>
```

EDIT: From console...

```
 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
        at HTMLDocument
```

From page source...

```
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/datepicker.self-6267be6d4d0f0e8665be3b4d6ac07f40ba23a32aff8eaa5d1bfc00f76a9eeae7.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

Any ideas? I have the juery-ui-rails gem loaded too. Thanks

Comment: Any errors in the console? How is your final html looks like?

Comment: Hi, added console error...

Comment: Seems like the `datepicker` library wasn't loaded. Check the HTML to see what loaded and what not.

Comment: I think you might be right, seems to be looking in assets, I don't have the files locally. I wonder is it to do with my application.css.scss?

Comment: this has nothing to do with CSS

Comment: @Dekel Does this help? $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (new:350)
    at j (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)

Comment: no, it's the same as before

Comment: Could problem be jquery version?